# Why are default Start Menu folders read-only in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, start-menu, read-only, attributes, files-folders

The default Start Menu folders in Windows 7 are marked as read-only.  When installers create new Start Menu folders (or the user manually creates new ones), they are not marked as read-only.

The default Start Menu folders include:

- Programs
- Programs > Accessories
- Programs > Administrative Tools
- Programs > Games
- Programs > Media
- Programs > Startup

Is there any reason the default Start Menu folders are marked with the read-only attribute?

Comment: What exactly are the *default* start menu folders?

Comment: @Berend Good question.  I have updated my question to answer yours. :)

Comment: This is just a wild guess, but I think that this is because these folders are shared between several applications, so removing one would have a greater impact. It would make sense to make it harder to (accidentally) remove such a folder. Other folders in the Start Menu often contain only one application, or are at least managed by a single company. FWIW, this is still the case in Windows 10.

Comment: @Berend I think that `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu`.

Comment: *Is there any reason the default Start Menu folders are marked with the read-only attribute?* Yes, this prevents accidental actions.

Comment: @Berend Can you think of any problem with removing the read-only attribute from such folders (besides increasing the chance of accidental deletion, which is this particular case is close to zero)?

Comment: I can't, really ;-) but why bother?